# Can't figure out how to use XML path

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-path

Hi I have tried all I can, but can't figure out how to do this.

I have this table "T1"

```
----RID----PID----
     1      1      
     1      2
```

which i left join on RID with another "T2" to get the name column of PID:

```
----RID-----PID-----Pname----
     1      1        Task1
     1      2        Task2
```

So far so good. But what I really want is at table with these columns: 1. (distinct RID) 2.(A count of PID's in each Rid) 3.( Comma-seperated string of all PID-names)

```
----RID-----PID-----Pname----
     1       2      Task1,Task2
```

But if a RID only has one Pname then here should be no comma:

```
----RID-----PID-----Pname----
     1       2      Task1,Task2
     2       1      Task1
```

Anyone ? I have tried with XML PATH but can't figure it out.....

Answer (score 0):

Full working example:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
(
    [RID] INT
   ,[PID] INT
);

INSERT INTO @T1 ([RID], [PID])
VALUES (1, 1)
      ,(1, 2);

DECLARE @T2 TABLE
(
    [RID] INT
   ,[PID] INT
   ,[Pname] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @T2 ([RID], [PID], [Pname])
VALUES (1, 1, 'Task1')
      ,(1, 2, 'Task2');


SELECT T1.[RID] 
      ,COUNT(T1.[PID]) AS [PID]
      ,[value] AS [PName]
FROM @T1 T1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + T2.[Pname]
            FROM @T2 T2
            WHERE  T2.[RID] = T2.[RID]          
            ORDER BY T2.[PID]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    )

) DS ([value])
GROUP BY T1. [RID]
        ,[value];
```

[image]